# subprocess in python showing attribute error

Tags: python, module, subprocess

the below code shows attribute error when run the below code.
    import subprocess
    import sys
    import shlex

```
cmd = 'mtr -nrc30 -s1400 -z'
cmd = shlex.split(cmd)
abc = shlex.split(sys.argv[1])
subprocess.call([cmd,abc])
```

the error i get is below. What could the possible reason for this, when both the inputs to subprocess are converted to list

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'rfind'

Comment: Show us the full error traceback.

Comment: Specifically, which line *of your code* is the error coming from?

Comment: Line 12 from the code, which is the line where subprocess is called out

Comment: `shlex.split()` returns a list.  So your argument to `subprocess.call()` is a list-of-lists, which is the wrong type.

Comment: What could be the soultion here, rather than giving the entire command in subprocess.call ?

Comment: Can you be more specific in what `abc` would tend to look like? If you're trying to append the arguments in `sys.argv[1]` to the arguments in `cmd`, you would just want to do `subprocess.call(cmd + abc)`.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy abc is supposed to be an Ip and yes the solution did work out to be proper. Thanx for the help

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of helping others with the same question: the issue here is this:

```
subprocess.call([cmd, abc])
```

where `abc` is a list of arguments you want to give the program specified in `cmd`, which were given to *your* program through `sys.argv`. What your current code ends up unpacking to, then, is the following:

```
# assume abc == ['arg1', 'arg2', ...]
subprocess.call([['mtr', '-nrc30', '-s1400', '-z'], ['arg1', 'arg2', ...]])
```

This isn't working, because it's a nested list. Subprocess only takes strings or a list of strings - so, to make it work, what you really want is

```
subprocess.call(['mtr', '-nrc30', '-s1400', '-z', 'arg1', 'arg2', ...])
```

This can be obtained by simply concatenating the two lists using `+`:

```
subprocess.call(cmd + abc)
```

Comment: Really appreciat it. Thank you